# Plotting a 2D Moving Image in MatLab

Tags: image, matlab, plot, 2d

I'm using matlab to model several particles moving in a 2d field. When using plot, I normally use plot(x,y,'rx'), which will plot these moving particles with a red x, but I want to use an image instead. I've tried using imread in place of 'rx', as well as a few other options, but matlab will not accept this. Does anyone have any solutions or tips I could use?